# MongoDB Java POJO confusion

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo

I have a class PubmedReference that has in addition to some public getters and setters a static method called fromArticle:

```
public class PubmedReference extends Reference {

@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$", message = " allows only numbers.")
private String pmid;

private String title = "";
private String authors = "";

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getAuthors() {
    return authors;
}

public void setAuthors(String authors) {
    this.authors = authors;
}

@BsonIgnore
public static PubmedReference fromArticle(PubmedArticle pubmedArticle) {
...
}

@BsonIgnore
public PubmedArticle getFromArticle() {
    return null;
}
```

First thing that is causing confusion is that I have to add a dummy getFromArticle() annotated with @BsonIgnore. Second despite of @BsonIgnore the Mongo Java driver requires me to register all POJOs for the PubmedArticle.class which is like > 20 classes, despite that it should ignore it anyway. Is this a bug in the driver or did I miss anything? I thought static routines are ignored? I'm using MongoDB Java Driver 3.6.3.

Thanks for helping me clarify this.

Comment: Seems the POJO registration is required because of the getFromArticle() dummy routine.

Comment: Removing the dummy routine solved my issue. Maybe a driver before 3.6.3 didn't ignored correctly static routines?